# setting VerticalScrollingOffset programmatically

Tags: c#, winforms, scrollbar

I'm using a custom scroll bar and the problem I'm facing now is that when I have thousands of rows in a datagrid and scroll all the way to the bottom, `dataGrid.VerticalScrollingOffset` is about + 400 higher thank `customScrollbar.Value`. Which ends up with dataGrid now showing last few records, because it hasn't scrolled down enough.

It would be perfect if I could set `dataGrid.VerticalScrollingOffset` value or get the maximum vertical scrolling value of dataGrid, I couldn't find any information on nether.

Currently I'm calculating the maximum value like `rowCount*rowHeight`, which doesn't give exact max value, therefore it's not scrolling down all the way. Any suggestions? Thanks!

Answer (score 3):

You can use [`FirstDisplayedScrollingRowIndex`][1]:

```
// To Scroll down
this.FirstDisplayedScrollingRowIndex = this.FirstDisplayedScrollingRowIndex + 1;
```

If you want to have per pixel increment, place the `DataGridView` in a `Panel` whose `AutoScroll` property is set to `true`.

Comment: Thanks, but I need a way to set pixel value, not row index.