# Touch screen - DataGridView not scrolling to the end

Tags: c#, visual-studio, datagridview

I have an application running on a touch screen. In it i have a DataGridView, and i have this problem:

When i scrool it using the touch screen it does not go to the end.

When i scrool it using the mouse it does go to the end.

Since my last touch screen related question did not get much love or answer i made a video to better demonstrate my problem: [LINK TO THE VIDEO](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=xTHdh196gEc&list=WL&index=38)

As u can see, when i use the touch screen there is a record missing and when i go to the scrool bar with the mouse its like the DataGridView adds another record. This has happen with more than just 1 row.

Any suggestions ?

**Info:**

App is running on win 10.
Made in .net(c#)(framework 4)

**EDIT:**

**right now i am trying this but its still too unpredictable**

```
            int totalHeight = 0;
            foreach (DataGridViewRow row in dataGridView1.Rows)
                totalHeight += row.Height;

            MessageBox.Show("Total H: " + totalHeight.ToString() + " Height: " + dataGridView1.Height.ToString() + " VO: " + dataGridView1.VerticalScrollingOffset);

            if (totalHeight - dataGridView1.Height < dataGridView1.VerticalScrollingOffset)
            {
                int diferenca = dataGridView1.RowCount - (dataGridView1.FirstDisplayedScrollingRowIndex + dataGridView1.DisplayedRowCount(false));

                MessageBox.Show("Diferenca- " + diferenca.ToString() + "RowCount- " + dataGridView1.RowCount + "Soma- " + (dataGridView1.FirstDisplayedScrollingRowIndex + dataGridView1.DisplayedRowCount(false)));

                if (diferenca != 0)
                {
                    dataGridView1.FirstDisplayedScrollingRowIndex = dataGridView1.FirstDisplayedScrollingRowIndex + diferenca;
                }
            }
```

Comment: Hi I have some problem right now. Did you find solution for that?

Comment: Hi, did you solve this problem?

Answer (score 0):

Try to do it programatically by setting VerticalScrollingOffset:

maybe this is helpful: [setting VerticalScrollingOffset programmatically](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14553702/setting-verticalscrollingoffset-programmatically)

Comment: `dataGridView.VerticalScrollingOffset` is read only.. Did you mean that i should use a custom scrool bar=

Comment: Try setting this property dataGridView.FirstDisplayedScrollingRowIndex

Comment: I can do it. But in what event do i do it?

Comment: Scroll up: this.FirstDisplayedScrollingRowIndex = this.FirstDisplayedScrollingRowIndex - 1 Scroll Down: this.FirstDisplayedScrollingRowIndex = this.FirstDisplayedScrollingRowIndex + 1;

Answer (score 0):

Try this, it works for me:

```
    private void dgv_Scroll(object sender, ScrollEventArgs e)
    {
        if (e.NewValue > e.OldValue && dgv.RowCount - 1 == (dgv.DisplayedRowCount(false) + dgv.FirstDisplayedScrollingRowIndex))
            dgv.FirstDisplayedScrollingRowIndex = dgv.RowCount - 1;
    }
```

also in some cases I use:

```
        private void dgv_Scroll(object sender, ScrollEventArgs e)
    {
        DataGridView dgv = (sender as DataGridView);
        int hidenRows = (dgv.RowCount) - (dgv.DisplayedRowCount(false) + dgv.FirstDisplayedScrollingRowIndex);

        if (e.NewValue > e.OldValue && hidenRows < dgv.DisplayedRowCount(false))
            dgv.FirstDisplayedScrollingRowIndex = dgv.RowCount - 1;
    }
```